# i want to have 2 primary keys for my website as phone number and email id

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, facebook-login, registration

i want to create a login system where user can get logged in by email or phone number, now i am confused how to create a table for these i.e 
if i took both email and phone as primary in the same table then it would become compulsory for user i want my user either logged in as phone or email whichever he/she has but also want.. just like Facebook which registers by email or phone ..

i hope u get the question right, if there if any i ANY way possible to achieve this. Please help me

Please don't bother, i'm a newbie

Comment: Have a primary key of ID, a column for email, and a column for phone number. Give these a unique constraint. They do not need to be a PK to be unique and usable as a log in name.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

What does a primary key in a table have to do with the requirements for logging in?  You seem confused.

In any case, I would imagine that you would have a table called `users` or something like that.  Then, you can have an auto-incremented `UserId` in the table.  This would be unique and would be the primary key of the table.

To avoid conflicts with `name` and `email`, each of these would be declared as unique (two declarations).

Then, you have the uniqueness you want.  Plus, a user can change his or her name or email and still be the same user.

Comment: if i create two tables one users which contains userid, username, password and another like user-information contains name, email, phone, address,...., and if i create email and phone unique then it will those email and phone will be unique for all userid in user table???

Comment: Why would you use two tables?  All those columns can go in one table.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it is nothing to do with the unique columns. its up to what variables he is accepting it. either email and phone number